# OpenGL lighting question?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, lighting

Greetings all,

As seen in the image , I draw lots of contours using GL_LINE_STRIP.
But the contours look like a mess and I wondering how I can make this look good.(to see the depth..etc )
I must render contours so , i have to stick with GL_LINE_STRIP.I am wondering how I can enable lighting for this?

Thanks in advance

Original image

http://oi53.tinypic.com/287je40.jpg

[image: http://oi53.tinypic.com/287je40.jpg]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think lighting should work normally (line strips are converted to very thin quads/triangles), as long as you supply a normal at each point, add lights and turn them on... Don't know if it'll make it look good though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:**

umanga, at first I thought lighting wouldn't work because lighting is based on surface normal vectors - and you have no surfaces. However @roe pointed out that normal vectors are actually per vertex in OpenGL, and as such, any POLYLINE can have normals. So that would be an option.

It's not entirely clear what the normal should be for a 3D line, as @Julien said. The question is how to define normals for the contour lines such that the resulting lighting makes visual sense and helps clarify the depth?

If all the vertices in each contour are coplanar (e.g. in the XY plane), you could set the 3D normal to be the 2D normal, with 0 as the Z coordinate. The resulting lighting would give a visual sense of shape, though maybe not of depth.

If you know the slope of the surface (assuming there is a surface) at each point along the line, you could use the surface normal and do a better job of showing depth; this is essentially like a hill-shading applied only to the contour lines. The question then is why not display the whole surface?

*End of update*

+1 to Ben's suggestion of setting the line colors based on altitude (is it topographic contours?) or based on distance from viewer. You could also fill the polygon surrounded by each contour with a similar color, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IsraelCVFRtopography.jpg

Another way to make the lines clearer would be to have fewer of them... can you adjust the density of the contours? E.g. one contour line per 5ft height difference instead of per 1ft, or whatever the units are. Depending on what it is you're drawing contours of.

Other techniques for elucidating depth include [stereoscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy), and rotating the image in 3D while the viewer is watching.

Comment: This is not entirely true though, lightning works using normal vectors, which are given per vertex and interpolated (or lighting is calculated per vertex and interpolated, doesn't matter), surface normals have nothing to do with it, as a normal vector can be interpolated along a line just as well as along a surface.

Comment: @roe: Can a line have a normal in R3? Normal vectors in R3 are usually defined as the cross-product of two other (non-collinear) vectors -- a surface has two non-collinear vectors, a line does not.

Comment: @Julien; Yes, a normal to a surface can be defined that way. OpenGL chose not to though (and rightly so), but rather to define normals as an explicit normal vector at each vertex. Even a point can have a normal in OpenGL, and as such could be shaded. A mathematical line would have no thickness either, and as such could not be visible on screen, yet it is (it's being rendered as triangles).

Comment: @roe, a good point, that points or lines *can* have normal vectors as far as OpenGL is concerned... editing my answer on that basis.

Comment: @umanga, I updated this answer to reflect @roe's point that lines can indeed have normals.

Comment: @LarsH thanks alot.Yes my contours are coplanar ,so I will try using vertex normal as you suggested.

Comment: @umanga, glad you find that helpful. Hope you can post a screenshot when you get something going that works.

Answer (score 4):

Lighting contours isn't going to do much good, but you could use fog or manually set the line colors based on distance (or even altitude) to give a depth effect.

Comment: +1 for suggesting fog, but -1, because specifying per-vertex normals will actually work just fine for line strips. Depth-dependent fog is probably the easiest to implement, so i'd give that a whirl (with lighting off) and see if the results are passable; otherwise, compute per-vertex normals for your contours, and try that.

Comment: @Matthew, why -1 to Ben? He didn't say per-vertex normals wouldn't work (i.e. couldn't produce lighting effects) for line strips... he just said it wouldn't do much good. Which is a valid opinion if your priority is to clarify depth.

Comment: Well, that may have come across as a bit more harsh than I meant! - but I do think lighting lines can provide some useful depth information, by using the surface normal (in this case, of the isosurface). It has been a long time since I have used this technique, so I may be misremembering its utility.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for shading then you would normally convert the contours to a solid. The usual way to do that is to build a mesh by setting up 4 corner points at zero height at the bounds or beyond then dropping the contours into the mesh and getting the mesh to triangulate the coords in. Once done you then have a triangulated solid hull for which you can find the normals and smooth them over adjacent faces to create smooth terrain.

To triangulate the mesh one normally uses the Delaunay algorithm which is a bit of a beast but there does exist libraries for doing it. The best of which I know of is the ones based on Guibas as Stolfi papers since its pretty optimal.

To generate the normals you do a simple cross product and ensure the facing is correct and manually renormalize them before feeding into the glNormal.

The in the old days you used to make a glList out of the result but the newer way is to make a vertex array. If you want to be extra flash then you can look for coincident planar faces and optimize the mesh down for faster redraw but thats a bit of a black art - good for games, not so good for CAD.

(thx for bonus last time)